# Creating User through My SQL Workbench for Database (AWS RDS). Received "Error Saving Account" - Access denied for User (using password:Yes)

Tags: mysql-workbench, amazon-rds

I'm really new to this so my explanation may not be very clear or detailed so please bear with me.

I've set up an EC2 instance and an AWS RDS using Elastic Beanstalk. I've set the inbound rules to allow for 3306 connection. I have been able to connect through MySQL Workbench using "Standard TCP/IP over SSH" connection method.

I am in the process of creating a user directly in the "User and Privileges" menu, but when I go and click on the "Apply" button, an error message pops up saying "Error Saving Account - Access denied for User XX (using password:Yes)".

I'm a bit stuck at this point, any help/suggestion would be awesome, thanks!

Comment: The user you used to connect to EC2 probably has not enough rights to create new users.

Comment: @MikeLischke Thanks for responding! But the account I'm using has UserAdmin, Security Admin, MonitorAdmin, DBManager, DBDesigned roles assigned. Also, it is the Master Account that I created in RDS. Any additional tips would be much appreciated!